# NodeJS this.var is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

*index.js*

```
const request = require('request');

class ScheduleDownloader {

ScheduleDownloader(schoolId, username, schoolPassword) {
    this.schoolId = schoolId;
    this.username = username;
    this.schoolPassword = schoolPassword;
}

getScheduleAtDate(dateString) {
    console.log(`https://${this.username}:${this.schoolPassword}@www.myurl.de/${this.schoolId}/vplan/vdaten/VplanKl${dateString}.xml`)
    /*request({url: `https://${this.username}:${this.schoolPassword}@www.myurl.de/${this.schoolId}/vplan/vdaten/VplanKl${dateString}.xml`}, (err, res, body) => {
        if(err) console.error(err);
        console.log(body);
    });*/    // COMMENTED OUT FOR TESTING
};

module.exports = ScheduleDownloader;


var s = new ScheduleDownloader(10192417, 'schueler', 'S53998t');
s.getScheduleAtDate(20200317); // For testing in this class
```

*Output*

```
https://undefined:undefined@mnyurl.de/undefined/vplan/vdaten/VplanKl20200317.xml // undefined
https://www.myurl.de/10192417/vplan/vdaten/VplanKl20200317.xml // What it should be
```

As you can see I am trying to request a xml-file. I found that this.username and so on are undefined.
How do I fix this? And whats the reason for this? (Sorry, I am new to Javascript)

Comment: Your class is missing a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to define those variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript constructor are called constructor, not with name of the class, so your function ScheduleDownloader is never called. 
Change it to constructor:
Some reading :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: I do the same, and both the syntax can became confusing sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how you declare constructor in es6.
Try this

```
constructor(schoolId, username, schoolPassword) {
    this.schoolId = schoolId;
    this.username = username;
    this.schoolPassword = schoolPassword;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) definition isn't setup correctly. I think you meant to use the `constructor`?

```js
class ScheduleDownloader {

  constructor(schoolId, username, schoolPassword) {
      this.schoolId = schoolId;
      this.username = username;
      this.schoolPassword = schoolPassword;
  }

  getScheduleAtDate(dateString) {
      console.log(`https://${this.username}:${this.schoolPassword}@www.myurl.de/${this.schoolId}/vplan/vdaten/VplanKl${dateString}.xml`)
      /*request({url: `https://${this.username}:${this.schoolPassword}@www.myurl.de/${this.schoolId}/vplan/vdaten/VplanKl${dateString}.xml`}, (err, res, body) => {
          if(err) console.error(err);
          console.log(body);
      });*/    // COMMENTED OUT FOR TESTING
  };
}


var s = new ScheduleDownloader(10192417, 'schueler', 'S53998t');
s.getScheduleAtDate(20200317); // For testing in this class
```